# What does the noun "rosy" mean in these lyrics?

Tags: meaning, nouns, lyrics

What does the noun "rosy" mean in the first line of [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKAQAxiEvy0) ?

> Well there's a ring around the moon a ring around the **rosy**
> A ring around my socks that keep my feet so cozy
> Well I'm a single woman and I don't need many things
> So why don't my poor little finger got a ring
> ...

Comment: It may be a reference to the children’s song “Ring Around the Rosy”.

Comment: Most native speakers would recognize it as part of the children's nursery rhyme, which is often said to refer to the Great Plague of 1665-6.

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UaspFUkcPjo) is an explanation of the nursery rhyme's lyrics. Whether one should consider 'rosy' here as the noun distribution requires, or as a mangled version of 'rose/s', or whether one should regard the grammar as idiosyncratic is moot.

Comment: There are other versions of the rhyme, for example "Ring-a-ring-a-roses" but I'm more curious about "A ring around my socks". Perhaps it means the elastic mark around her ankles. There is a ring around everything, but not her finger.

Comment: so the answer is: rosy = roses = plural of rose (usual meaning of that word) ?

Comment: "so the answer is: rosy = roses = plural of rose?"  I would say no.  To my ear, the meaning is only a reference to the nursery rhyme.  I think it would be wrong to imagine that the singer is claiming the existence of some kind of ring that encircles one or more roses.  We're only meant to think of the nursery rhyme (and the rhyme with "cozy" in the next line)

Comment: The singer is mentioning things that have a ring, leading to her complaint that her finger does not... it's just a song. She isn't claiming anything about there being a ring around any 'rosy': it's just a line from *another* old song.

Comment: "Ring-a-ring o' roses" is the British version I grew up with. I only learned years later that Americans sing "Ring around the rosy".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a song lyric based some puns on an old nursery rhyme.  It's not intended to make sense.

Comment: @KateBunting That's the version I know as well. I understand that a 'ring o' roses' referred to a circle of pink or red lesions that appeared on the body of an infected person and was the main external sign of infection. What "a ring around the rosy" is supposed to mean I have no idea.

Comment: @BoldBen - My understanding is that the ring surrounded a pink middle.